# Legend not getting displayed -Dojo

Tags: dojo, dojox.charting

I am beginner trying out charting example using DOjo..This is a code I picked from this forum. I am able to see the graph but unable to see the legend at all...

Is the fault in the widget declaration or some files missing?
All the files are availbale in my system though.. I am thoroughly lost..

```js
    dojo.require("dojox.charting.Chart2D");
    dojo.require("dojox.charting.Chart2D");
    dojo.require("dojox.charting.themes.PlotKit.blue");
    dojo.require("dojox.charting.widget.Legend");
    dojo.require("dojox.layout.FloatingPane");
    dojo.require("dojox.charting.themes.MiamiNice");
    dojo.require("dojo.colors");

    makeCharts = function() {
      var chart1 = new dojox.charting.Chart2D("simplechart");

      chart1.addPlot("default", {
        type: "StackedColumns",
        markers: true,
        tension: 3,
        shadows: {
          dx: 2,
          dy: 2,
          dw: 2
        }
      });
      chart1.addAxis("x", {
        labels: [{
          value: 1,
          text: '18-Mar'
        }, {
          value: 2,
          text: '19-Mar'
        }, {
          value: 3,
          text: '20-Mar'
        }, {
          value: 4,
          text: '21-Mar'
        }, {
          value: 5,
          text: '22-Mar'
        }, {
          value: 6,
          text: '23-Mar'
        }]
      });
      chart1.addAxis("y", {
        vertical: true
      });

      chart1.addSeries("Four", [196, 209, 77, 218, 48, 243]);

      chart1.addSeries("One", [266, 158, 131, 228, 217, 262]);

      chart1.addSeries("Three", [296, 214, 267, 80, 40, 225]);

      chart1.addSeries("Two", [207, 264, 115, 227, 193, 27]);

      chart1.setTheme(dojox.charting.themes.MiamiNice);


      chart1.render();
      var legend = new dojox.charting.widget.Legend({
        chart: chart1,
        horizontal: true
      }, "legend");


    };

    dojo.addOnLoad(makeCharts);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/resources/dojo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css" media="screen" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js" data-dojo-config="isDebug: true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>

<body class="tundra">
  <div id="simplechart" style="width: 350px; height: 150px;"></div>
```

Kindly help..

Answer (score 4):

I'm add some code like this

```
<div id="legend"></div>
```

Under this code

```
<div id="simplechart"  style="width: 350px; height: 150px;"></div>
```

And I got this picture.

[image: show legend]

Is that you need right?

(I'm not strong in english, sorry for that.)

Answer (score 0):

dojox.charting.widget.Legend needs a container node (Like div). 
In your case, adding :

`<div id="legend"></div>`

after :

`<div id="simplechart" style="width: 350px; height: 150px;"></div>`

should do the trick.